# Android NullPointerException while reading idata from sdcard

Tags: android

In my code I have stored some images to an **SDCARD** successfully. Now, I'm trying to read those images from the **SDCARD**, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to read the file.

This is my code:

```
// list of available files in  path
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();   
File[] listFile;

String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/saved_images";

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
for (File file : files){          
    // This line shows error
    imageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add two checks.

```
if ( !targetDirector.exists())
   return; and display toast

if (files==null)
   return; and display toast
```

Comment: I edited my code,but it didnt work.And then i restarted my system now it works perfectly.